# Tesseract not recognizing digits correctly from OpenCV preprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

[image]

I'm trying to OCR these digits. However, tesseract is not recognizing them properly.

import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

```
image = cv2.imread('PATHTOIMAGE', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 2)
mask = cv2.inRange(gaussian, (250, 250, 250), (255, 255, 255))
ocr = image_to_string(mask, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(ocr)
```

The masking result is the following:
[image]

OCR result: 88311

I tried performing some morphological operations from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) (dilating and opening), but no luck.

I also tried to detect contours and detect digit by digit, but also no luck.

How else could I improve?

Comment: You may try some of the `--psm` options, such as `--psm 5`  https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/

Comment: Awesome. However, it's confusing 2 with 8. Any preprocessing suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve correct results without the scaling and Gaussian blur steps. I also inverted the mask and used only `--psm 6`

```py
image = cv2.imread('PATHTOIMAGE', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
mask = cv2.inRange(image, (250, 250, 250), (255, 255, 255))
ocr = image_to_string(~mask, config='--psm 6')
print(ocr)
```

For what it's worth, I cannot recreate the 2 vs 8 confusion error. I am running tesseract 4.1.1 and pytesseract 0.3.8 on windows.

If you still need to explore other preprocessing steps, consider running a sequence of erosion and dilation operations with asymmetric kernels. For example

```py
kernel = np.ones((6,2), np.uint8)
img = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, 1)

kernel = np.ones((2,40), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, 1)

kernel = np.ones((1,40), np.uint8)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, 1)

kernel = np.ones((4,2), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, 1)
```

Numbers are for your scaled image. This appears to remove the vertical points on the 2 while retaining other relevant information. You will need to tune and ensure it works for all number options.

Comment: Bravo. Well done. I played with this myself and couldn't get it to work. It seems the scaling in the OP is what messes up the recognition. Anything above 2x scaling seems to not work.